# Network share issue

Tags: windows, networking

I have access to a network share. If I access it by \SHARENAME, some files are unable to be opened/accessed. If i access it through a drive name, like S:\, those files are able to be manipulated. Is there a reason a difference exists even though it goes to the same place?

Comment: Do your NTFS permissions match the share permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds to me like you're connecting to the mapped share with differing permissions (i.e. as another user).